# How to access cells table view without select and change it with another class?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, cell

I have two pages, one a Map and second List table view

[image] [image]

As you see in Map Page with two buttons

1-If I click on one of two buttons, show me a popup

[image]

2- And if click on ok, the background will be yellow

[image]

3- In my list will be yellow on same text, too.

[image]

Also if tap on green button on the right side, each of cell will be yellow.

I am doing All of that (with **Swift 3**) except **phase 3**

Another words, I want click on ok button of popup in Map page and then change the a cell which same name label on List page table view.

I think, I get access to any cell but I don't know, how to do that!

If you think another approach, recommend me.

My table view Class:

```
import UIKit

class StudentListVC: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    let students: [String] = ["Blue Hacker","Black Hacker","White Hacker","Brown Hacker","Blue Hacker"]

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!


    // create a cell for each table view row
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CardCellVC

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.studentNameLabel.text = students[indexPath.row]
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        print("row is \(indexPath.row)")        

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.students.count
    }



}
```

and My cell Class:

import UIKit

```
class CardCellVC: UITableViewCell, UITableViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet var container: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var studentNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var leftButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var rightButton: UIButton!


    let containerHeight = 60.0
    let studentLabelHeight = 60.0 - 20.0
    let buttonSize = 20.0
    let yCard = 0.0

    var studentListVC = StudentListVC()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        //// Initialization code
        let wids = studentListVC.view.frame.width

        container.frame = CGRect(x: 10.0, y: yCard, width: Double(wids-20.0), height: containerHeight)
        container.tag = 0
        container.dropShadow()

        studentNameLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 50.0, y: containerHeight/2-studentLabelHeight/2, width: Double(container.frame.width)-100, height: studentLabelHeight)
        studentNameLabel.tag = 5

        leftButton.frame = CGRect(x: 10.0, y: containerHeight/2-buttonSize/2, width: buttonSize, height: buttonSize)
        leftButton.tag = 1
        rightButton.frame =  CGRect(x: Double(container.frame.width)-10.0-buttonSize, y: containerHeight/2-buttonSize/2, width: buttonSize, height: buttonSize)
        rightButton.tag = 10

        rightButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CardCellVC.tapOk), for: .touchUpInside)
        leftButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CardCellVC.tapCancel), for: .touchUpInside)


    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    }
@objc private func tapCancel(){
        //
        studentNameLabel.backgroundcolor = UIColor.yellow
    }


    @objc private func tapOk(){
        //
        studentNameLabel.backgroundcolor = UIColor.white
    }
```

Comment: You don't need to access the cell but your array that you load the table. Without any code is hard to point how to do that, but when you call your list, you can pass a parameter that let you identify which item of your array must be selected

Comment: I bring simple code

Comment: Don't think I got it. But the important step is from your step 2 to step 3. How are you calling your table view from your Map White Hacker ?

Comment: in my cell class, i make a card (with e.g."white hacker") and call it in my map class `viewdidload`, but i dont bring here because very long